# How do I transfer properties of one button to another? (Text in this case, python, tkinter)

Tags: python, button, text, tkinter

My question is pretty simple, I'm still a beginner and I'm expecting there to be a very simple solution for my problem, but I'm having trouble dealing with it myself. I have a button let's call it button1, and it has a text inside of it, i just want to transfer the text inside, to another button.

The text of course changes all the time within the program I'm making so I can't just copy it once and be done with it. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Also, how can I extract a text from a button? For example, I have;

```
button1.config(text="X")
```

How do I pull it out into a variable that I can use around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `button1['text']` to set and get it's value. This is true for most objects in tkinter. `cget` is alternative method.

```
button2['text'] = button1['text']
```

OR

```
button2.config(text=button1.cget('text'))
```

Or any combination of those methods really.